# LibGdx Bow and arrow game physics

Tags: libgdx, 2d, physics

I'm working on a new game written with LibGdx Engine and Java.
I've got a problem with some of the physics in this game.

I want to shoot the arrow in a ballistic trajectory (angry bird style)
and can't find the equation to do so .

I am using these velocity equations:

```
    float velx = (float) (Math.cos(rotation) * spd);
    float vely = (float) (Math.sin(rotation) * spd);
```

I add this to the current position and the arrow shoots in one direction - straight.

I thought maybe changing the rotation would help me achieve what I want (a ballistic path).

It does help, but I want to have the trajectory as well.

I saw this
ProjectileEquation class that someone already posted but didn't know how to work with it:

```
 public class ProjectileEquation
{

  public float gravity;  
    public Vector2 startVelocity = new Vector2();  
    public Vector2 startPoint = new Vector2();  
    public Vector2 gravityVec = new Vector2(0,-10f);

    public float getX(float n) {  
        return startVelocity.x * (n ) + startPoint.x;  
    }  

    public float getY(float n) {
        float t = n;
        return 0.5f * gravity * t * t + startVelocity.y * t + startPoint.y;  
    }
```

}

I'm looking for some help to help me use this class for ballistic trajectories.

This is how I tried using it:

```
    for(int i =0;i<30;i++)
            {
                Texture f = ResData.Square_1;
                ProjectileEquation e= new ProjectileEquation();
                e.gravity = 1;
                e.startPoint = new Vector2(bow.getX(),bow.getY());//new Vector2(-bow.getX(),-bow.getY()); //My bow is opposite so it suppose to work fine
                e.startVelocity = getVelocityOf(bow.getRotation());
                Vector3 touchpos = new Vector3();

                s.draw(f,e.getX(i) ,e.getX(i),5,5);

            }
```

Comment: What do you need? I didn't understand good enough. Do you need to render your trajectory?

Comment: Yes, can't manage to use this class for doing it

Comment: If you don't have air resistance then your trajectory is simple parabola. Equation http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/6/0/5/605184454f022e69b228699e8983c9c3.png

Comment: I need it to change the angle of the arrow when it flys
and to understand how to put this equation into code, gravity, 
Nah not working with air resistance at this time

Comment: Use equation only for rendering trajectory. For movement set Vector velocity at start and then in update method use velocity.y -= gravity.y * deltaTime; to change body's velocity (velocity.x keeps unchangable). Use velocity.angle to get arrow's angle.

Comment: btw trajectory of arrow fired from bow is a spiral (like in film `Wanted` with more then one rotation) with large radius up to 1.5m (did not see any bigger) I know for any one not using bow this might be silly but it is true. If you shoot wrong the radius is big if you shoot correctly the radius is small almost invisible. simple air friction is not enough because arrow is far from mass point. it is long with not equally dispersed mass, has mostly dynamic wings, body is flexible and it s bending during the flight and also shoot itself (see spin number of arrow)

Comment: If you want more realistic simulation you should try to shoot from bow first to see what I mean. here some numbers I measured: My 35 lbs Longbow with base is shooting arrows with avg speeds 137km/h (132km/h with puffs installed) measured on 10 meters with 240 fps camera. the speed is dependent also on firing style (before I change styles I measured 147km/h ...), length of drag, arrow mass and spin number... The rotation inertia is very important to trajectory do not ignore it ...

Comment: Wrong spin number has tendency to turn arrow to left/right, wrong locking point of arrow on bowstring has effect that change trajectory to sinusoid saw amplitudes around 0.2m with wavelength around 30-100 cm. Sorry for long comments but I have seen many bow games and almost none of them realistic at all ...

Comment: Are you using box2d?

Comment: I would strongly consider using box2d

Answer (score 0):

The ProjectileEquation class you post looks like it'll calculate the X and Y position given a time delta, so the float you pass in should be the time delta since you started the arrow moving (in seconds).

That code will not give you the angle of the arrow though. To find that, I would suggest you keep hold of the previous X and Y, then you can use Math.atan2() to calculate the angle based on the previous XY and the current XY. Google atan2 for a load of info on how to use it.

The very best way to do this however would be to use Box2d and model the scene correctly. Then you wouldn't have to get involved in the maths at all. I read somewhere that that's what Angry Birds uses, and is an excellent choice for modelling these sorts of physics games.

I hope your game goes well.